# javascript es5 Angular2 compontent templateurl relative path not working

Tags: javascript, angular

in ts component use templateUrl,need add moduleId property ,but it not work in javascript.

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'dashboard.component.css' ]
})
```

how to translate ts to javascript ??

```
(function(app){
    var DashboardComponent = function (){

    };
    DashboardComponent.annotations = [
        new ng.core.Component({
            selector:'my-dashboard',
            template: '<h3>My Dashboard</h3>',
            moduleId:module.id,
            templateUrl:'dashboard.component.html'
        }),
    ];
    app.DashboardComponent = DashboardComponent;
})(window.app=window.app||{})
```

Comment: If you're using angular-cli, mek sure you are executing `ng serve` on a terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

To transpile typescript to javascript, you need to run the Typescript compiler or one of the many tools that use this compiler internally.

I suggest you follow along and build [the QuickStart project](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) to get an idea.

Comment: I want to use javascript . but in javascript the code moduleId:module.id  not work.